# Is it possible to print loop's data outside the loop , before ending the loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I want to write a program in which I will print 'done' for infinite times and besides I also print the number of times, I have printed 'done'.But I think I made the process harder.
Is  this possible to  print the output  like exact my code  output using only loop or any easiest or simple way ?

```
import os

from time import sleep
from IPython.display import clear_output

temp=""
count=0
while(True):
  count+=1
  for i in range(0,count):
    temp+="done"
    temp+="\n"
  print("Total Done :",count)
  print(temp)

  temp=""
  sleep(1.5)
  os.system("clear")
  clear_output()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. I don't understand what you mean by "using only loop or any easiest or simple way"; as far as I can tell, that describes the code you already have. In general, though, questions about making the code simpler or more elegant are off topic here.

Comment: You don't need the inner loop: `temp = "done\n" * count`

Comment: Could you reword your question a bit, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by "Is it possible to print loop's data outside the loop". Data does not "belong to" loops.

Comment: I mean, can I see the same output without using clear_output or using only loop?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inner loop or  `time.sleep` to do this.

```
import time
starttime=time.time()
duration=1.5
temp=0
count=1
while(time.time()<(starttime+duration)):
    print("done \n")
    temp+=1
    print("Total Done :",temp)
```

New to python coding myself. :P